# remove "all" php files from ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to uninstall php5 using commands like:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5, 
sudo apt-get -y purge php.*
```

But now it turns out that I have half installation of php5, because when I run `php5 -v` command in terminal, it displays the version of php instead of saying that php5 does not exist.
How do I delete all php related files so that I can install it back properly again?

Comment: On running 'apt-get remove --purge php5-cli' command I get:-                                                                                                     The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: php5-cli but it is not going to be installed E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get remove --purge php5-cli
apt-get remove --purge php-cli
```